# create sub list of list item with no children

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Little help need with jquery sortable.

I have a nested list like so:

```
<div id="tree">
<ul>
    <li class="n-1">root
        <ul>
            <li class="n-2">Academic
                <ul>
                    <li class="n-5">Staff</li>
                    <li class="n-6">Courses</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="n-3">Administration</li>
            <li class="n-4">Technical
                <ul>
                    <li class="n-6">Courses</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and an associated list:

```
<div id="orphans">
    <ul>
        <li class="n-47">a</li>
        <li class="n-48">b</li>
        <li class="n-49">c</li>
        <li class="n-50">d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I need is to create an unordered list when dragging a LI so that when hovering over a li in the target list with no child list that new list is created - and remove it when leaving if the item was not dropped into that list.

Quickest soln would be to get the current element being hovered over but having a spot of bother catching that with sortable.

here is what I have so far:

```
$('#tree ul li li , #orphans ul li')
    .addClass('closed')
    .live('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass( 'open closed');
    });

$('#tree ul ul')
    .sortable({
        items: 'li',
        connectWith:    '#tree ul ul',
        cursor:         'crosshair',
        helper:         'clone',
        zIndex:         999,
        placeholder:    'sort-highlight',
        opacity:        '0.6',
        over:           function(event,ui)
                        {
                            $(this).children('li.closed').toggleClass( 'open closed');
                            $(this).children('li:not(:has(ul)').append('<ul><li class="dummy">DADADA</li></ul>');
                        },
        out:            function(event,ui)
                        {
                            $('li.dummy').remove();
                            $('ul:empty').remove();
                        }
    })
    .disableSelection();


$('#orphans ul')
    .sortable({
        items: 'li',
        connectWith : '#tree ul',
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        helper: 'clone',
        zIndex: 999,
        placeholder: 'sort-highlight',
        opacity: '0.6'
    })
    .disableSelection();
```

any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed a work around if anyone is interested....

instead of the over and out options I have used start and end.

```
start: function(event,ui)
       {
           $(this).find('li').not(':has(ul)').append('<ul><li></li></ul>');
           $(this).sortable('refresh');
       } ,
stop:  function(event,ui)
       {
           $(this).find('li:empty').remove();
           $(this).find('ul:empty').remove();
           $(this).sortable('refresh')
       }
```

If anyone has better solution please please please let us know...

Answer (score 1):

Actually , i don't have the same diposition of list as you , i saw inside an li you can have ul and li !

```
> <li class="n-2">Academic
>                 <ul>
>                     <li class="n-5">Staff</li>
>                     <li class="n-6">Courses</li>
>                 </ul> 
> </li>
```

i only got :

```
 <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
    <li id='1' class="ui-state-default"><span> stuff ...</span></li>
    <li id='3' class="ui-state-default"><span> stuff ...</span></li>
    <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
         <li id='1' class="ui-state-default"><span> stuff ...</span></li>
         <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">     
                <li id='4' class="ui-state-default"><span> stuff ...</span></li>   
         </ul>
    </ul>
    <li id='2' class="ui-state-default"><span> stuff ...</span></li>  
</ul>
```

in my jquery function i've got this in start :

```
start: function(event,ui)
      {
     $(this).find('li').next().not('ul').after('<ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable"><li class="hiddenli" style="height:0.1em;"></li></ul>');        
    $(this).sortable('refresh');
       }
```

So i manage your version to work with my list^^ , but i get i also get a droppable zone after my current element i'm dragging, so i can placemy li as children but since the parent is the element which i'm dragging, it's not possible i'd like to remove the

creating after my element i'm dragging and that trigger the start event !

For the update on sort i tried and failed using serialize don't know how to get the question and it's children and order it correctly i don't know where my

has been drop (which parent it has , and if it's in a list with other li which place it has , beceause as you can see on the screenshot, i got a number for each item (1-2-3-4) the last one represent the order in the list which has parent id=3  you see , i've been trying for days :(