# jQuery : Append child + sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I need to sort some `li`'s but I don't know how to add a children to an empty `li`. At this moment I can add `li`'s to another `li` only if is not empty.

EG.

```
<ul>
     <li id="1">Item</li>
     <li id="2">Item
         <ul>
            <li id="3">Item</li>
            <li id="4">Item</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="5">Item</li>
     <li id="6">Item</li>
</ul>
```

So I can add li_1 into li_2 but I can't add li_6 into li_5 because li_5 is empty.

My work can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k83QH/).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to add empty ul with an padding / margin than you can drop the items into this empty sublist. 
http://jsfiddle.net/k83QH/2/

Comment: Yes this can be a solution but I need to add a lot of code. I need this to be created dynamically with jquery.

Please check the update - http://jsfiddle.net/k83QH/3/

I added something but it doesn't work.

Comment: @LoWE in your example is an error because there are a few elements which have the same id

This example is a fast solution for your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/k83QH/4/

Comment: Hmm .. your new code doesn't work. However is good start. Thanks!

Comment: Reffering to this question and it's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336314/create-sub-list-of-list-item-with-no-children)
I changed the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/k83QH/11/

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this would be to add an empty ul, in jQuery, to any list items that could potential have children dragged into them. That way you'll get the drop container for all of your li's

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check whether there is any ul child element for that li, if not, then add a ul element, and then add your child li elements in it.