# How can I create a sublist with jquery sortible

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I was trying to make a list with sublists with jquery sortible. when I was busy with this I ran into the problem that I coudn't create a sublist when I  tried to drop na li on another li.

the code i have now:

```js
$('.sortable-folder').sortable({
        connectWith: '.sortable-folder',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //var prev = $(ui.item).prev('li').attr('id');
            //var next = $(ui.item).next('li').attr('id');
            $("ul").each(
                function () {
                    var elem = $(this);
                    if (elem.children().length == 0) {
                        elem.parent().removeClass("has-children");
                        elem.remove();
                    }
                }
            );
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2-12" id="menu-mappen">
   <ul class="sortable-folder">
    <li class="active"><a id="id1" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
    <li><a id="id2" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
    <li><a id="id3" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Homepage</a></li>
    <li class="has-children"><a id="id4" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Bestanden</a>
      <ul class="sortable-folder">
        <li><a id="id5" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
        <li><a id="id6" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="id7" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336314/create-sub-list-of-list-item-with-no-children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336314/create-sub-list-of-list-item-with-no-children)

Comment: the problem with that example is that the current item is not added to the sublist and that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: I tested it and it adds empty sublists when dragging starts. Those sublists get added to the sortable, so you should be able to drop it inside an empty (new) sublist. When dragging stops it removes all empty sublists again.

Comment: do you have a working sample of this? because I do not get it work.

Comment: It seemed to work, but it strangly does not. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying with the code below... Only problem is the `$(this).sortable('refresh');` seems to get called to early (or not at all) so the added sublists are not sortables.

(If someone knows how to fix that, feel free to edit this answer.)

```js
$('.sortable-folder').sortable({
        connectWith: '.sortable-folder',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        start: function(event,ui)
        {
            $(this).find('li').not(':has(ul)').append('<ul class="sortable-folder ui-sortable"><li></li></ul>')
            $(this).sortable('refresh');
        } ,
        stop:  function(event,ui)
        {
            $(this).find('li:empty').remove();
            $(this).find('ul:empty').remove();
            $(this).sortable('refresh');
        }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
.sortable-folder {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.sortable-folder li {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
<div class="col-2-12" id="menu-mappen">
   <ul class="sortable-folder">
    <li class="active"><a id="id1" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
    <li><a id="id2" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
    <li><a id="id3" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Homepage</a></li>
    <li class="has-children"><a id="id4" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Bestanden</a>
      <ul class="sortable-folder">
        <li><a id="id5" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
        <li><a id="id6" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="id7" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```